# How to call a function with data location as parameter using web interface designed in sublime?

Tags: solidity

How to call a function with data location as parameter using web interface designed in sublime?  Please find the Solidity code below:

```solidity
contract Demo{
  string public name;

  function setName(string memory  _name) public{
    name= _name;
  }
  function getName()view public returns (string memory){
    return name;
  }
}
```

The Function call is made in `.html` file:

```js
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var new_contract= new web3.eth.Contract([
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "_name",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "name": "setName",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getName",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "name",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}
],"0x0df91edadefbf4dd5ae655d1e7db48f4623863f3");

var contract= new_contract; 
var pre=document.getElementById("output");
var input=document.getElementById("input");
var button=document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
  contract.setName(input.value);
  output.innerHTML=contract.getName();
})
```

But I am getting an error on wepage which says:

> Uncaught TypeError: contract.setName is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is `contract`?  Could you show how you create it?

Comment: The Question is updated. Please Check @Mikhail Vladimirov. The Contract is just a variable to initialize the smart contract.

Comment: What version or implementation of Web3 are you using?

Comment: How do you connect to web3? Are you using metamask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```js
contract.methods.setName(input.value);
```

instead of

```js
contract.setName(input.value);
```

See [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#id26) for details.

Comment: i have tried that also. But it is not working